# Dell XPS 15 logout on overheat

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, overheating, dell-xps

When I am running `gcc` build on my notebook, the following temperature indication happens:

```
$ sensors
...
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +97.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +89.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +79.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +96.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +83.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +80.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +79.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

First temperature is always very close to 100 degrees. Nothing helps, including additional cooler panel. When temperature goes higher than 100 degrees, the logout happens.

The questions are:

1) Are these indication correct? The coolers of notebook start to work and plastic become very warm near Caps Lock button, but I would not say it is very hot.

2) Is it possible to change CRIT to 120 degrees and/or disable logout?

3) Is it possible to make CPU not becoming so hot?

---

```
dimskraft@studebaker:/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon1$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Mo"
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
```

---

Here is the trace, how `Clion` started to index files. You see, that some of the cores are balancing very close to 100 degrees. Once some of them cross the crit, I will get logout and loose my progress.

What to do?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your logs for messages explaining why the session manager is quitting or being killed?

Answer (score 0):

1) *Are these indication correct?* Heat's measured under the lid of the [FCBGA](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/Flip_Chip_Ball_Grid_Array) CPU package, on the processor die. A lot of work has gone into making measurement tools accurate. I have personally seen CPU temps significantly higher than their surroundings, for plastics and the fiberglass substrate of circuit boards are not efficient heat conductors.

2) *Is it possible to change CRIT to 120 degrees and/or disable logout?* Don't know. However, that's a good way to damage the CPU and void your warranty. CPU manufacturers specify limits after extensive testing, and they know better than you or I what their circuitry will withstand.

3) *Is it possible to make CPU not becoming so hot?*  Yes.

Laptops generally don't have room for better coolers, but you can often improve on the heat transfer of the existing cooler by removing the cooler, cleaning the heat sink and CPU package lid, lapping the surface of both for better flatness, and replacing the heat sink compound with better-than-factory compound and installation.

The conduction of heat from CPU package to heat sink is only slightly improved, typically from 11% to 20%, by compound, and excess compound will reduce heat transfer efficiency. If the outside of the CPU lid and the bottom of the heat sink were as flat as a [Jo block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_block), no compound would be needed; compound only fills in the air gaps caused by imperfections in the surfaces.

Cleaning the interior of the laptop is another way to improve heat transfer.